# Issue Downloading Plain Text File in Spring Controller from Web App

Tags: java, spring, servlets, controller

I'm having an issue where I am trying to download a simple "text/plain" file in a spring controller method. I'm getting the text that I exactly want in the web tools response when running the app, which is "test". The response headers in the web developer tools are as follows:

- Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt
- Content-type: text/plain
- Content-length: 4

Length is 4 since that's the number of bytes that the text "test" is. In the controller, I have produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE. When I click the associated button in the application to download the file, however, rather than showing the download in the web browser, the download is made to the disk because the file.txt actually shows up in my project's workspace in intellij (which I'm using for my IDE). So, my question is how do I get the download to occur in the web browser, meaning what happens when you click on the 'Download Source Code' button at the following link https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-download-file-controller-example/, rather than the file downloading to my workspace/disk?

The support methods/classes look like the following:

```
public class TextFileExporter implements FileExporter {
   @Override
   public Path export(String content, String filename) {
      Path filepath = Paths.get(filename);
      Path exportedFilePath = Files.write(filepath, content.getBytes(), 
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
   }
}

public interface FileExporter {
   public Path export(String content, String filename);
}
```

The controller at hand is the following:

```
@GetMapping(value="downloadFile")
public void downloadFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   String filename = "example.txt";
   String content = "test";
   Path exportedpath = fileExporter.export(content, filename);
   response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
   Files.copy(exportedpath, response.getOutputStream());
   response.getOutputStream.flush();

}
```

Comment: If you're using Spring MVC, avoid hand-managing low-level details like `HttpServletRequest`. Instead, return `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` for a download like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using directly the Response entity to return an InputStreamResource

```
@RequestMapping("/downloadFile")
        public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
            String filename = "example.txt";
            String content = "test";
            Path exportedpath = fileExporter.export(content, filename);
            
            // Download file with InputStreamResource
            File exportedFile = exportedPath.toFile();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(exportedFile);
            InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(fileInputStream);
            
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + fileName)
                    .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .contentLength(exportedFile.length())
                    .body(inputStreamResource);
    }
```

As @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic said try avoiding using low level objects, let it handle it by Spring itself

Comment: This unfortunately produced the same result, a download to my IDE workspace and onto my disk.

Comment: But that's something actually normal. I mean the file needs to be stored somewhere anyways while the user download it. The question is does it not download the file also from the browser itself?

Comment: Correct, it still does not download from the browser itself. When I click the relevant button, the download just goes straight to the code workspace.

Comment: What are you using to call the endpoint? I've replicated the controller with the same exact code I wrote on my answer and your part of the code of the 'export' part and it works like a charm from Chrome, the file was downloaded correctly into my downloads folder